# How to find all the files related to a software?

Tags: files, find

I'm not sure if it is possible, but if it is, how can I find all the files related to a software? For example, is there any way to find all files that `gedit` needs and uses to work?

Does such command/techniques gather files like `/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/oblivion.xml` which is not dedicated only to a certain software or owned by a different one?

Answer (score 6):

To list files belonging to a package, run

```
$ dpkg -L packagename
```

<sup>Note: does not include configuration files, usually.</sup>

To find the package a file belongs to, run

```
$ dpkg -S /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a non-trivial problem, I'm afraid. Some approaches that might help you:

- You can find all the files installed by a particular package by looking in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/gedit.list`.
- You can find all of the other packages on which `gedit` depends by running `apt-cache depends gedit`. (Conversely, you can find all the packages which depend on `gedit` with `apt-cache rdepends gedit`). Bear in mind that these functions aren't recursive - for `gedit` to successfully run requires a great deal of your system - eg, the C library, the X graphics system, the dbus system message bus...
- You can find out which library files an executable requires at runtime by running `ldd $(which gedit)`. (`which gedit` returns the path to the actual executable run when you run `gedit`, in this case `/usr/bin/gedit`).
- You can find out which files a given process has (currently) open by running `lsof -c gedit`. (The program may load files, eg icons into memory at startup and close their file descriptors, which won't show up in such a list).